# Cant resolve constructor ArrayAdapter for custom dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

The thing is i m using a different layout b.xml to show a dialog in layout a.xml. And i dont know the code for arrayadapter which i write in a.xml will work in b.xml.[This is the error which i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56nMz.png)

Comment: Or use `context`.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I tried this and is still doesn't work getting the same error.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I tried using context it doesn't give error but content i not displayed in list view.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried [context] and is still doesn't work getting the same error.

The dialog probably uses different theme from the activity (light vs dark). For inflating views inside the dialog you need to use themed context of that dialog.

```
new ArrayAdapter(dialog.getContext(), android.R.layout..., arr);
```

---

There are two more errors that explain why you see no content:

```
final ListView lv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

You were looking for the list view in the activity instead of the dialog.

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You weren't setting the adapter to the list view.

Answer (score -1):

I can see `findViewById` in your code. So you are using `Activity`.

In your `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.Simple_list_item_1, arr);` line, `this` keyword refers the anonymous inner class of `OnclickListener`. You have to use `Your_Activity_Name.this` instead of `this`.

Hope it helps:)